# Allow empty cell values of an excel sheet in mule 4

Tags: json, excel, dataweave, mule4

While reading an excel sheet I need to show all the column values even if they are empty.

But mule is not considering the empty cells unless the last cell has a value.

My requirement is that I need to map all the column values even if they are empty.

Dateweave script looks like this:

```
%dw 2.0
var myInput = readUrl("classpath://Book1.xlsx", "application/xlsx")
output application/json
---
myInput.'Sheet1' map ($ mapObject {
    "$$" : $
})
```

HTTP listener settings is:

```
<http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="ed1c0abb-8f7a-4856-b305-d0a249a07c96" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/test" outputMimeType="application/xlsx; tableoffset=A2; ignoreemptyline=false; header=true"/>
```

The image below may showcase better:

[image]

Comment: Give me the contents of a CSV file to regenerate the input.  Moreover, I did check the reader properties for an xlsx file and there is nothing that will force to read the empty columns AFAI can tell.  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-formats#reader-properties-for-excel.  There is a way to get it done though, I 'll do for you once I have a bit of time, probably tonight.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r0Kk8x9cpAbB7nALsD8xneCRWGw6Eu-x)

Comment: I created a xlsx based on your sample spreadsheet and used your sample DW script, but was not able to reproduce the issue. I am getting empty strings in the JSON output for all blank cells in the spreadsheet. Using mule runtime 4.2.1 and studio 7.3.2 on mac.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to just use CSV files if possible.  If you have no choice give this a try, the rest of the code should be as is in your snippet:

```
var blank = myInput.'Sheet1' reduce (
    (e, acc=[]) -> acc ++ (e pluck $$)
) 
distinctBy $
reduce (
    (e, acc={}) -> acc ++ {(e): ""}
)
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects
---
myInput.'Sheet1' map (
    blank mergeWith $
)
```

For some reason I was NOT able to bring read and parse an xlsx (because of a bug) probably in the latest version of studio with is what I used, but the snippet above should work for you.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it works with this problem. But I am supposed to provide a generic/reusable solution. Column names will change with different kind of records.
Actual dataweave looks like this:
```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json 
--- 
payload.'MASTER' map ($ mapObject {
 (camelize(lower(($$ replace " " with "_")))): if (isNumeric($)) ($ as String as Number) else $
})
```

Comment: Then you need to collect and get the distinct list of all fields because you apply `mergeWith`.  Hold on...

Comment: I updated my original solution so that you calculate the blank object based upon your inputs.  The only think that I change is the blank object the rest is the same.